# Changing defaults

Tags: mysql

Ok let me rephrase. This is what my table is described as.

```
    mysql> describe department;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dnumber | int(1)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dname   | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mgrssn  | varchar(9)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is what I need my table to be described as:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| dnumber      | int(1)      | NO   | PRI | NOT NULL|
| dname        | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| mgrssn       | varchar(9) | YES  |     | NULL    |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
```

How do I change the default of dnumber to make it not null from null?

Answer (score 1):

Since `dnumber` is the primary key of the `department` table, it *cannot* have a null value.

So, what will happen if you actually try to insert the following?

```
INSERT INTO department(dname, mgrssn) VALUES ("test", "123456789");
```

You'd expect the insert to fail with an error.  But no, it succeeds, (albeit, with a warning):

```
mysql> INSERT INTO department(dname, mgrssn) VALUES ("test", "123456789");
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
```

What just happened? Well, turns out to be one of MySQL's [many gotchas](http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html#1_1), where "*NULL is NOT NULL*".  Today's MySQL manual [says pretty much the same thing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html#id913518):

> If a column definition includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL determines the default value as described in [Section 11.5, “Data Type Default Values”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html).

So, what actually got inserted?  Let's take a look:

```
mysql> select * from department;
+---------+-------+-----------+
| dnumber | dname | mgrssn    |
+---------+-------+-----------+
|       0 | test  | 123456789 |
+---------+-------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What happened here was that MySQL took that insert statement that was implicitly trying to insert `NULL` into `dnumber` and quietly converted it to the default value for `INT`, or 0.

There's also a [really good video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PoFIohBSM4) that describes this and other strange things MySQL does (as compared to [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)) in more detail.

Finally, let me add one more piece of advice - since it is the primary key, it's a really good practice to make `dnumber` an auto-incrementing column, like this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE department MODIFY dnumber int(1) AUTO_INCREMENT;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.27 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc department;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| dnumber | int(1)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dname   | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mgrssn  | varchar(9)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That way, future inserts into `department` won't always try to insert another 0 for `dnumber` causing a duplicate key error, but will instead use the next lowest available integer value, e.g. 1, then 2, then 3, etc.

Hope this helps!